# Traffic lights on a timer from pageload

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have been doing JavaScript in school for about 3 weeks, and yes this is coursework, but we are coming to the end of our time, and I will get more marks for working code than I will lose for asking for help.

I have written this code to run through the traffic light sequence, and have recently added the on load function, as well as setinterval. Basically it's not working, and only having done JavaScript for three weeks, I don't know if its a syntax error, or logic. Would someone tell me what's wrong and offer a solution as close to my current code as possible?

Edit: when I run this currently, the traffic light displays as red, but never changes, also, it must have no user interaction to get most marks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="javascript:timer()">

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<img id="traffic" src="Red.jpg">

<script>
var list = [
    "Red.jpg",
    "Red-Amber.jpg", 
    "Green.jpg",
    "Amber.jpg"
];
var index = 0;
function changeLights() {
     index = index + 1;      
if (index == list.length) 
index = 0;           


var image = document.getElementById('traffic'); 
    image.src=list[index];
}

function timer(){ = setInterval(changeLights(),1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For future reference, press the F12 key while the browser is open and focused, and this will open up the developer console. In the above code, the console would show a SyntaxError that the = sign was used unexpectedly (e.g. in the wrong place), so that could have given you a hint as to where the problem was

Comment: thanks, i launched it in firefox, then used that debugger, but it wasn't very specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timer function is wrong, it should be:

```
function timer(){
setInterval(changeLights,1000);
}
```

I removed the '=' and the changeLights should NOT have parenthesis after it.

Answer (score 0):

replace the timer function with

```
var traficTimer = null;
function timer(){ 
traficTimer= setInterval(changeLights(),1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function timer(){
 setInterval(changeLights,1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Maurice Buiten Suggested you have to use setIntervel instead of setTimeOut. check the blow working code snippet.

```
</head>
<body onload="timer()">
<img id="traffic" src="Red.jpg">

<script>
// global variables
var list = ["Red.jpg","Red-Amber.jpg", "Green.jpg","Amber.jpg"];
var index = 0;

// funnction for changing lights
function changeLights(){
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length){
        index = 0; 
    }       
    var image = document.getElementById('traffic'); 
    image.src=list[index];
}

 // time out function
 function timer(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        changeLights();
    }, 1000);
 }
</script>
</body>
```